# Sorting Multidimensional Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to sort a multidimensional array but unfortunately i weren't able to do it.
It 's an integer array which the user is allowed to put its dimensions ,its elements and get the result in a descending order. Here is what i have done . Thanks

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int rows;
        int columbs;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows");
        rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of columbs");
        columbs = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] number = new int[rows, columbs];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements of the array");

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < columbs; y++)
            {
                number[i, y] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        int a;
        int z;
        int w;

        for (w = 0; w < rows; w++)
        {
            for (z = 0; z < columbs; z++)

                if (number[w, z] < number[w, z++])
                {
                    a = number[w, z++];
                    number[w, z++] = number[w, z];
                    number[w, z] = a;
                }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (int k in number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: every `z++` increments `z`. I don't think your intension is this. Use `z+1` . BTW: it is the right time to learn how to debug an app.

Comment: i ahve trien z+1 and error occur saying that " Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: Because it is not the only bug in your code. As I said, You can't find always someone to help you. Try to learn debugging.

Comment: implement IComparer in a class then pass it to the array.sort(yourarray,yourIcomparerimplementation);

Answer (score 0):

```
if (z+1 < columbs && number[w, z] < number[w, z+1])
            {
                a = number[w, z+1];
                number[w, z+1] = number[w, z];
                number[w, z] = a;
            }
```

Between, it's **Columns** instead **Columbs**.